Puzzled about matching cases and patterns
I am puzzled why this does something sensible:
list = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5} 
roll = list /. {a__, pivot_, b___} :> {b, pivot, a}
(*{4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3}*)

i.e, the pattern matching makes sense to me:
the pattern a matched 3
pivot was 1
b was Sequence[4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]
@eyorble documentation suggest in the comments explains why
and this doesn't pick out the same patterns
Cases[list, {a__, pivot_, b___}, All]
(*{{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5}}*)

$VersionNumber (*14.2*)

I expected that this would return the match for a,pivot, and b.
But note that
Cases[list, {a__, pivot_, b___} :> {b, pivot, a}, All]

returns the same result as the list /. {a__, pivot_, b___} :> {b, pivot, a} above.
This is similar to a comment by  Carl Woll here: Difference in pattern matching between Cases and ReplaceAll
Can someone help me understand what is going wrong.
I'm trying to implement a quicksort with //.  and rules.  This is just a test case.

In 12.1 the result of Cases is equivalent to {list}, i.e. it identifies the same match as //..

Hidden away in tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules in the help, there's a note that reads "A pattern like f[x__,y__,z__] can match an expression like f[a,b,c,d,e] with several different choices of x, y, and z. The choices with x and y of minimum length are tried first." As for Cases, it looks like in 13.1 it probably destructs the list first, attempting to match the list pattern with each individual element. Try Cases[{list}, ...] instead?

I think the previous comments basically answer the question, but can you please provide the version you're using to reduce confusion for anyone in the future seeing different results.

Edited the post.  Initially, I made a copy-paste error (sorry!)  Still puzzling though.  I don't have 13.1 to see if there is a difference

You said Cases[list, {a__, pivot_, b___}, All] doesn't pick out the same patterns, but I think it does. The output, showing list matches the parttern, does not contradict my thought. Why do you think it does? Did you think you'd get the output of Cases[{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5}, {a__, pivot_, b___} :> {{a}, {pivot}, {b}}, All]?

@MichaelE2  Thanks, I think I understand now.  Previously, I think I was thinking (but no longer sure) that I would get {{3},1,{4,1,5,26534}} and {3,1},4,{4,1,5,..}, etc.  But, I see now that that was muddled thinking.  This post can be closed now...

Have you seen ReplaceList[{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5}, {a__, pivot_, b___} :> {{a}, {pivot}, {b}}]?

@MichaelE2  Cool. That was what I was looking for. Thanks
